# cite inside a csv file

Tags: citing, csv, csvsimple

I am trying to create a table from a csv file that has a citation column. Here is a sample from the csv file:

```
id, ref
1, \cite{ref1}
2, \cite{ref2}
```

when I use:

```
\csvreader[ 
  respect all, 
  before reading={\tiny},  
  head to column names,  
  autotabular]
  {Res/myTable.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow} 
\small
```

I get:

```
id, ref
1, “cite–ref1"
2, “cite–ref2"
```

Is it possible that the ref column is interpreted as a citation providing that ref1 and ref2 are already in my bib file.

Regards!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragments into a compilable document that people can play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem to have code in the CSV file as long as you don't begin a row with a backslash (`\`). But you need to remove the `respect all` key from your `\csvreader` command, since that makes *all* characters normal characters.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
id, ref
1, \cite{ref1}
2, \cite{ref2}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{ref1,
    Author = {Joe Author},
    Publisher = {Some Press},
    Title = {A title},
    Year = {2018}}

@book{ref2,
    Author = {Sam Author},
    Publisher = {Some Press},
    Title = {Another title},
    Year = {2017}}

\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvreader[  
  head to column names,  
  autotabular]
  {\jobname.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow} 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]